# Strange link error when #ifdef #else is defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I face a very strange link problem with VC 2010. Now I am developing a C++ library, and in order to make debug much easier, for some functions the library provides two function interfaces. For example,

```
class Object
{
  public:
   int fun(std::vector<int> &auxiliary_variable_for_debug_purpose); 
   int fun();
 }
```

It is also possible to reorganize this class in this way:

```
    class Object
    {
      public:
#ifdef DEBUG_INDICATOR
       int fun(std::vector<int> &auxiliary_variable_for_debug_purpose); 
#else
       int fun();
#endif
     }
```

By doing so I except to give a clear interface to the user.

The problem I face now is both `int fun(std::vector<int> &auxiliary_variable_for_debug_purpose);` and `int fun();` will invoke another function called `void help_function()`, which is declared and defined in separated files.

```
file.h
void help_function()
```

and

```
file.cpp
void help_function()
{
  // do something
}
```

As you can see `void help_function()` is the same regardless whether `DEBUG_INDICATOR` is defined or not. If I defined `DEBUG_INDICATOR`, I can compile the class with `int fun()` function without any problem. However, when I undefined `DEBUG_INDICATOR`, the error `LNK2001` error happens, suggesting unresolved external symbol void `help_function()`. I have tried every possible means to figure it out, but failed. Any ideas will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The library I have built is a dynamic library. Regardless whether `DEBUG_INDICATOR` is defined, the library can be built, and the link error only happens when the library is invoked.

Comment: What is your exact error message?

Comment: You use `int fun(std::vector<int> &auxiliary_variable_for_debug_purpose);` when `DEBUG_INDICATOR` is defined not `int fun()`.

Comment: 1. give us the complete error message. 2. did you try to rebuild the whole solution?

Comment: @Ben Sorry to reply late, the exact error message is Error 75 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl help_function() referenced in function "public: int fun()

Comment: @Dialecticus Sorry to reply late, and the exact error is  Error 75 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl help_function() referenced in function "public: int fun()

Comment: Does the linker produces 74 other errors before this one error? If so then maybe the problem is not specifically related to this one function. But we can't begin to guess what would that main problem be, because we do not have enough information.

Comment: So based on what we know, the lack of DEBUG_INDICATOR causes the body of help_function() to be missing. 

What else does DEBUG_INDICATOR control? is it referenced anywhere in file.cpp? What happens if you move the void help_function() {...} code to the same file that you implement Object::fun()?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not posted the exact error message you are getting, [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx) might help you.

Tip: Be specific while asking your question if you wish to receive accurate answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The exact error is that external symbol void help_function() can not be resolved. I do not have more information either.